# template using a non-existent main html tag in template block

Tags: html, angular

I got a theme which inside app.component.ts file on template block contains:

```
<main [class.menu-collapsed]="isMenuCollapsed" baThemeRun>
<div class="additional-bg"></div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

AFAIK this  element should have somewhere a selector referencing it but I am not able to find it anywhere. maybe this main tag is something internal for angular 2 and automatically loaded?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you share your code repository?

Comment: Well, this is the theme repository: https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, found the answer to your question.

> The `<main>` tag is new in HTML5.

The  tag specifies the main content of a document. Check this [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_main.asp) about this tag.